# jQuery - why are the text fields getting empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events

I have a page where the user can select a pre-defined client in a select box. My javascript is loading the contact name and adress from DB, but if the user selects `free`, he gets text input fields where he can type a free contact.

I use simultaneous change and ready events to do that, I also added `.change()` at the end of the function. I need to use those both events, because I want my page to run the ajax when page is ready AND when user change the select box.

The problem is when selecting the `free` option and typing name, adress, zip and so on, all the input text fields (used in the `id_client == free` condition) don't keep text, they get empty...

I will appeciate any help to fix that ! I'm a JS newbie, so maybe you will find other little (or bigger) things to fix :-)
Thank you for your help!

```
$(document).on('change ready', function(){
$(".select_client").ready(function() {

var e = document.getElementById("InputClient");
var id_client = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

if (id_client == "free") // values are not empty
 {
 $('div#contactCatcher').html("<div class=\"form-group\"><label for=\"ContactNom\">Nom</label><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"contact_nom\" id=\"ContactNom\"></div><div class=\"form-group\"><label for=\"ContactAdresse\">Adresse</label><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"contact_adresse\" id=\"ContactAdresse\"></div><div class=\"form-group col-xs-6\"><label for=\"ContactCodePostal\">Code postal</label><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"contact_code_postal\" id=\"ContactCodePostal\"></div><div class=\"form-group col-xs-6\"><label for=\"ContactVille\">Ville</label><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"contact_ville\" id=\"ContactVille\"></div><div class=\"form-group\"><label for=\"ContactPays\">Pays</label><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"contact_pays\" id=\"ContactPays\"></div>");
}
else if (id_client) 
{
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://satch/suivi-hbl/misc/scripts/get_client.pl", // URL of the Perl script

    // send id_client and name as parameters to the Perl script
    data: "id_client_facture=" + id_client,

    // script call was *not* successful
    error: function() { 
        alert("script call was not successful");
    }, 

    // script call was successful 
    // perl_data should contain the string returned by the Perl script 
    success: function(perl_data){
        $('div#contactCatcher').html(perl_data);
    }
});   
}

else {
$('div#contactCatcher').html("Veuillez s\&eacute\;lectionner un client.");
//  $('div#contactCatcher').addClass("error");
}

$('div#contactCatcher').fadeIn();
return false;
}).change();
});
```

And here is part of the HTML:

```
    <!-- ----------------- Show client ---------------- -->
    <p><div id="contactCatcher">Veuillez s&eacute;lectionner un client.
    </div></p>


    <!-- ----------------- Selection client ---------------- -->
    <form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="script.pl">

    <div class="form-inline">
        <label for="InputClient">Client &nbsp; </label>
            <select class="form-control select_client" name="id_client_facture" id="InputClient">
            <option value="">Select please</option>
            <option value="1">John Woolof</option>
            <option value="2">Marc Dabrani</option>
            ......
            <option value="free">Other</option>
            </select>
    </div>

    ........
```

Comment: Can you show your html code please ?

Comment: Of course. I updated my post with HTML. But I have to say that the problem comes from the HTML part which is inside the JS (in the `if (id_client == "free")` condition) and not from the main HTML.  By the way, the rest of this JS works well, i's only the input fields that get empty...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found. I doubled the whole function! It's certainly not the best way to solve that problem and not very clean, but it works... First function is used for `change()` event, the second for `ready()`. In the second, I didn't double the html return code that is not needed in my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".select_client").change(function() {

var e = document.getElementById("InputClient");
var id_client = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

if (id_client != "free")
 {


if (id_client) 
{
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://satch/suivi-hbl/misc/scripts/get_client.pl", // URL of the Perl script

    // send id_client and name as parameters to the Perl script
    data: "id_client_facture=" + id_client,

    // script call was *not* successful
    error: function() { 
        alert("script call was not successful");
    }, 

    // script call was successful 
    // perl_data should contain the string returned by the Perl script 
    success: function(perl_data){
        $('div#contactCatcher').html(perl_data);
    }
});   
}

else {
$('div#contactCatcher').html("Veuillez s\&eacute\;lectionner un client.");
//  $('div#contactCatcher').addClass("error");
}


$('div#contactCatcher').fadeIn();
return false;

}
else
{
$('div#contactCatcher').html("<div class=\"form-group\"><label for=\"ContactNom\">Nom</label><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"contact_nom\" id=\"ContactNom\"></div><div class=\"form-group\"><label for=\"ContactAdresse\">Adresse</label><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"contact_adresse\" id=\"ContactAdresse\"></div><div class=\"row\"><div class=\"form-group col-xs-6\"><label for=\"ContactCodePostal\">Code postal</label><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"contact_code_postal\" id=\"ContactCodePostal\"></div><div class=\"form-group col-xs-6\"><label for=\"ContactVille\">Ville</label><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"contact_ville\" id=\"ContactVille\"></div></div><div class=\"form-group\"><label for=\"ContactPays\">Pays</label><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"contact_pays\" id=\"ContactPays\"></div>");
}

});


}).change();








$(document).ready(function(){
$(".select_client").ready(function() {

var e = document.getElementById("InputClient");
var id_client = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

if (id_client) 
{
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://satch/suivi-hbl/misc/scripts/get_client.pl", // URL of the Perl script

    // send id_client and name as parameters to the Perl script
    data: "id_client_facture=" + id_client,

    // script call was *not* successful
    error: function() { 
        alert("script call was not successful");
    }, 

    // script call was successful 
    // perl_data should contain the string returned by the Perl script 
    success: function(perl_data){
        $('div#contactCatcher').html(perl_data);
    }
   });   
}



});


});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `div#contactCatcher` is not in form tag and in `if (id_client == "free")` you add input tag without form tag.

Try to add form tag around your input tag when Id_client is free.

2. I have tested your code and make some modification. I think the error is in your use of `.change()` and `.ready()`.

Please try code below. I hope that will help you.

html:

```
<!-- ----------------- Show client ---------------- -->
<div id="contactCatcher">
    <p>Veuillez s&eacute;lectionner un client.</p>
</div>


<!-- ----------------- Selection client ---------------- -->
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="script.pl">

<div class="form-inline">
    <label for="InputClient">Client &nbsp; </label>
        <select class="form-control select_client" name="id_client_facture" id="InputClient">
        <option value="">Select please</option>
        <option value="1">John Woolof</option>
        <option value="2">Marc Dabrani</option>
        ......
        <option value="free">Other</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#InputClient").change(function() {
    var id_client = $(this).val();

    if ($(this).val() == "free") // values are not empty
    {
        $('div#contactCatcher').html("<div class=\"form-group\"><label for=\"ContactNom\">Nom</label><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"contact_nom\" id=\"ContactNom\"></div><div class=\"form-group\"><label for=\"ContactAdresse\">Adresse</label><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"contact_adresse\" id=\"ContactAdresse\"></div><div class=\"form-group col-xs-6\"><label for=\"ContactCodePostal\">Code postal</label><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"contact_code_postal\" id=\"ContactCodePostal\"></div><div class=\"form-group col-xs-6\"><label for=\"ContactVille\">Ville</label><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"contact_ville\" id=\"ContactVille\"></div><div class=\"form-group\"><label for=\"ContactPays\">Pays</label><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"contact_pays\" id=\"ContactPays\"></div>");
    }
    else if ($(this).val() == "") 
    {
        $('div#contactCatcher').html("Veuillez s\&eacute\;lectionner un client."); 
    }else {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://satch/suivi-hbl/misc/scripts/get_client.pl", // URL of the Perl script

            // send id_client and name as parameters to the Perl script
            data: "id_client_facture=" + id_client,

            // script call was *not* successful
            error: function() { 
                alert("script call was not successful");
            }, 

            // script call was successful 
            // perl_data should contain the string returned by the Perl script 
            success: function(perl_data){
                $('div#contactCatcher').html(perl_data);
            }
        }); 
    }

    $('div#contactCatcher').fadeIn();
    return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: You're right. I moved the form tag before `div#contactCatcher` but it doesn't fix the problem. I suspect that the `change` event forces the values of the input tags to be blank...

Comment: @Satch Yes. I have edited my answer. Hope it's help you !

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately, your code only works for `change()`. The `ready()` function doesn't execute if one of the `id_client_facture` is already selected when the html page is ready. But I finally found a solution (below). Not so pretty, but it works. Thank you anyway for your help Mindsers ! Trop cool !!